# Rendering a variable to ejs template

Tags: node.js, ejs

I am reading a file synchronously and sending the content to a variable:

```
// Load the fs (filesystem) module
 var fs = require('fs');

// Read the contents of the file into memory.
var text = fs.readFileSync('testfile.txt').toString()

// index page
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index', { var:  text });
});

app.listen(8080);
console.log('8080 port');
```

Then in my ejs file (index.ejs) i have inserted the variable like this:

```
<main>
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h2><%= text %></h2>
        </div>
    </main>
```

I get this error that "text" is not referenced:

```
>> 14|    <h2><%= text %></h2>
   15|         </div>
   16|     </main>
   17|     </footer>

text is not defined
```

How do you render a variable to ejs?

Comment: Ok i figured it out.  :)  I removed the keyword var from the declaration of the text variable and then changed the res.render part too:
text = fs.readFileSync('testfile.txt').toString()

// index page
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index', { text });
});

Answer (score 2):

```
// Load the fs (filesystem) module
var fs = require('fs');

// Read the contents of the file into memory.
var text = fs.readFileSync('testfile.txt').toString()

// index page
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
 res.render('index', { text:  text });
});

app.listen(8080);
console.log('8080 port');
```

Do not remove var keyword from the variable declaration instead remove var keyword when you render a page to text..

And it should work.